# Border outer div depending on inner content

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a div wrapper `.outter` which can have any number of `.inner-wrapper` divs. These have any number `.element` divs. From level to level there are either the same number of elements or fewer elements. This creates a kind of pyramid at the bottom.

I would like to give the `.outter` wrapper a border and/or box-shadow. The contours of the `.inner-wrapper` should be traced directly. Importantly, there should be no border between the red and the blue elements where they touch. I don't know if this is possible without any complicated calculations using JS.

As I said, it can also happen that red and blue are the same width, i.e. have the same number of elements. However, a lower `.inner-wrapper` element will never have more elements than an upper `.inner-wrapper` element.

```css
.outter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-top: unset;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.element.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outter">
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="element red"></div>
    <div class="element red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is how it should mostly looks like: The black thing is the desired bored along the whole stuff.
[image]

Comment: If this is a React app you should show your JSX and tag it. The solution is ideally data-driven and not CSS. You'd add a class to elements which do or do not meet your criteria in React.

Comment: FYI, it's "outer".

Comment: Can you provide an image of what this is **supposed** to look like?

Comment: Sure i add a image

Answer (score -3):

To achieve the desired effect of having the border of the .outter wrapper follow the contours of the .inner-wrapper divs without creating a border between the red and blue elements where they touch, you can utilize the box-shadow property with inset shadows. This will create the effect of the border following the inner wrappers while avoiding the border between adjacent elements.

```css
.outter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px; /* adjust padding as needed */
}

.inner-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}

.element.red {
  background: red;
}

/* Add the following for border effect */
.outter::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px black; /* Adjust the shadow color and width as needed */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

This will create a border effect for the .outter wrapper that follows the contours of the .inner-wrapper divs without creating a border between adjacent red and blue elements. Adjust the box-shadow properties as needed to achieve the desired visual effect.

Comment: It would make sense if you added HTML to the snippet, so we can actually directly see what this renders like. (Adding the HTML from the question to the CSS you currently presented here, does not look anything like what was asked for though.)